# Applescript or Shell Script to Extract Text & Date from Email & Make Calendar Event

Tags: bash, calendar, applescript, automator

I need to create a script that takes a consistently-formatted conference room reservation request - name, date, time, duration, room number - (all on separate lines), and creates a Calendar Event that contains that same information. It will run automatically as a Rule in Apple Mail.

I understand the basics of AppleScript and Bash scripting, and have researched this question far and wide, but I'm stumped. I'm able extract the date with an Automator Quick Action that takes all text, extracts the date, and then passes the result to this Applescript, but that only creates a Calendar Event on the specified date, without the start or end time, and without the variables like the name and room number. I've been unable to add that info by trying to set and get those variables:

---

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set dateString to the clipboard
    set start_date to date (dateString)
    set end_date to date (dateString) 

    tell application "Calendar"
        tell calendar "Local"
            make new event at end with properties {summary:"PersonName", start date:start_date, end date:end_date}
        end tell
    end tell 

    return input
end run
```

---

Any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks.

---

12-10-18

The moderator asked me to provided sample use-case data in exact formatting. I hope I'm responding correctly. That data appears in the body of the email as:

```
    Name: [person's name]
    Date: [reservation date]
    Room Number: [requested meeting room number]
    Start Time: [start time]
    End Time: [end time]
```

Comment: Please provide sample use-case data in the exact formatting you will be using.  Surround the data by tags `<pre>` at the start and `</pre>` at the end to place it in a code block.  Edit the question to do this, don't add it in the comments section.  Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for what you provided, but it's insufficient.  It's important that actual data are provided in the fields, to provide us with date formats and time formats, in any and all variations they might occur.  Also, please confirm that each line starts with 4 spaces in front of the text ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I know nothing about Applescript, I'm going to give you a totally different approach.  Consider creating an .ICS file.  You may be able to then add the event to a calendar by issuing the command 'open <.ics file>'.

I created my .ics file using python: Here was my import:

```
from ics import Calendar, Event
```

You may find another approach to create the .ics file other than python if python is not your thing.  For example, another approach may consist of replacing variables in a here document in bash.  You can generate a template from an .ics file you export from your calendar.

You may find that an .ics file is more portable, too.  .ics is a standard format understood by many calendaring systems (certainly Apple).

In my simple project, I generated an .ics file to hold tennis events imported from a spreadsheet.  I was then able to email the .ics to all of the participants so they could load it into whatever calendaring this they were using.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That's an approach I hadn't considered, but it might be easier. I'll research that tonight.

Comment: pbell: Thanks very much. Just a quick look at that code showed me some things I was doing wrong. Your assumptions were correct. I'll try that script tonight and report back. I really appreciate your having responded, and in such detail.

Comment: CJK - The sample data I included is exactly how the data appear in the body of the email, minus the brackets. Each line does NOT have four spaces before it in the actual email. When I was adding that comment I was prompted by an apparent script on this site to add four spaces before each line. The body of the email is simply five lines, each with the indicated heading; each heading followed by a colon; and each colon followed by the specified word(s), date, and times.

Comment: @Alex Yes, but you haven't indicated how dates and times are formatted.  Are they `12/04/2018`, `2018-04-12`, `04-12-2018`, `4 December 2018`, etc. ?  And times ?  `12:30 PM`, `16.30`, `4.30PM`, `16:30:00`, etc. ? This is why it's important to have actual data.  I could have solved your problem a week ago if you'd provided this information.  (PS. Tag a user with the `@` symbol so they get notified of your reply.)

Comment: CJK - I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. Date format is: 12/15/18. Time format is: 16:30. I can alter either or both formats if that would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems to solve : 1) extract /check data from email text 2) create new event in iCal from data.

You've done the second part already: create calendar event from data.

By far, the most difficult part is to extract data from a non structured free text (even worth because it is rich text !) in email body. This is the role of the 1st sub-routine in script bellow.

It uses Applescript's text item delimiters with ":" and I add other delimiters because the content of an email is not a text, but a rich text (include returns, line feed,...). I assume that a line of text with "Name" must be followed by ":" and the name (one or few words). Same for room and date. For start/end time, the line must contain "Start"/"End" and after the ":", I assume the time is set with hours:minutes.

For instance the body bellow is valid :

```
Name: Stackoverflow 
Date: 21/12/18 
Start Time: 13:30 
End Time: 15:45
Room Number: Board Room
```

Note : the lines can be in any order. here the Room number is last line.

In script bellow, I assume the email to used is the first email selected in Mail. Up to you to adjust that part.

```
property myCalendar : "Local"

tell application "Mail" -- extract the selected email and get its content as list of paragraphs
    set mySelection to selection
    set myMail to first item of mySelection
    set myLines to every paragraph of (content of myMail)
end tell

set myEvent to ExtractfromRichText(myLines) -- parse the paragraphs to make a record {EName, ERoom,EStart,EEnd}
if EName of myEvent is not "" then CreateNewEvent(myCalendar, myEvent)
-- end of main

-- *******************
on ExtractfromRichText(LocalLines) -- convert the rich text with fixed format into a data set
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":", return & linefeed, return, linefeed} -- to remove all rich text end lines
    repeat with aLine in LocalLines
        try
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Name" then set LName to text item 2 of aLine
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Date" then set LDate to date (text item 2 of aLine)
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Room" then set LRoom to text item 2 of aLine
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "Start" then
                copy LDate to LStart
                set hours of LStart to ((text item 2 of aLine) as integer)
                set minutes of LStart to (word 1 of (text item 3 of aLine) as integer)
            end if
            if text item 1 of aLine contains "End" then
                set LEnd to LDate
                set hours of LEnd to ((text item 2 of aLine) as integer)
                set minutes of LEnd to (word 1 of (text item 3 of aLine) as integer)
            end if
        on error -- unexpected format
            log "error"
            return {EName:""} -- not proper email format for calendar events. return empty name
        end try
    end repeat
    return {EName:LName, ERoom:LRoom, EStart:LStart, EEnd:LEnd}
end ExtractfromRichText

-- *******************

on CreateNewEvent(LCalendar, LEvent)
    tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar LCalendar
    make new event at end with properties {summary:EName of LEvent, location:ERoom of LEvent, start date:EStart of LEvent, end date:EEnd of LEvent}
    end tell
end CreateNewEvent
```

Comment: pbell: I sent myself a test email with the exact contents as yours, copied the above script, and saved it to the scripts folder in the Mail program. I then selected that email and ran the script. While the script appears to run and doesn't return any errors, it doesn't make a calendar entry. My test calendar is named, "Rooms". I tried changing "LCalendar" in the fourth line from the bottom to that, but it made no difference. Have I failed to make some elemental adaptation such as that?

Comment: If your calendar name is "Rooms", you just need to replace, in the 1st line, "Local" by "Rooms".  I set "Local" before because it was in your example.

Comment: pbell: I made that change, but it still doesn't make a calendar entry.

Comment: I assume you checked the calendar name (exactly same spelling/letters).Then it is probably the data of your email. In routine ExtractfromRichText, you can see that it goes through each line of the mail and try to find keywords 'Name', 'Date', 'Room', 'Start', 'End'.  Each line containing one of these words should be followed by ':'. Add a log in the loop to check what's after these ':' (text item 2). Keep in mind that after Date, it should be valid date and after Start/End, it should be 2 numbers also separated by ':' like 15:30. The log will tell you where it fails and why.